# How to analyse SQL Server error log for shutdown due to issues?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know how to analyze error logs for shutdown due to issues. Is there any article explaining this? If yes kindly share it with me.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no shortcuts here.  If your server isn't behaving as you expected, you will need to work your way through the log item by item.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on that? If i understood what you are asking, search for SQL Server Extended Events.